# Android SQLite and GAME MODE Logic

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a game and I want to add modes to it. What I can't figure out is if I need a separate database for each mode, or if I can structure the DB to have multiple scores for each mode and pass the mode and score in a sort of if else if statement.

Could any body shed some light or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the only difference is the type of game mode played, but the rest of the score data is the same or similar, i'd just add a field to the highscores table so it might be: (_id, mode, date, name, score)
if the data is very different (like in one mode you just have a traditional high score but in another you track many different metrics, a different table might be in order.

in the first scenario, you don't need an if else statement, you just say insert into highscores (mode, date,name,score) values ("easy",'4/14/11',jkhouw1,'over 9000')...

then when you get the scores back, you just query where mode=yourDesiredMode